# Variadic Function for Kronecker Product

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I'm having trouble constructing a variadic function that does a particular task. For my particular example I'm using 2x2 matrices but you could imagine that my issue generalises to many data types. Also, for my example, "eye" is the 2x2 identity matrix.

Ok, so I would like to construct a variadic function f whose inputs might be (to give 3 examples):

```
f(Y, 2, Z, 5, X, 3)
f(X, 4)
f(X, 2, Y, 1)
```

where X, Y, Z are matrices, and the numbers are positive ints. It should return the following pseudo-code kronecker products, respectively:

```
KroneckerProduct(eye, Y, X, eye, Z)

KroneckerProduct(eye, eye, eye, X)

KroneckerProduct(Y, X)
```

So essentially it applies a matrix at the position in the KroneckerProduct specified by the int that follows the matrix, and fills in identity matrices in between.

Due to my inexperience with variadic functions, I haven't gotten far with it. My biggest problem is getting 'recursive' step of the variadic function to do what I need (see comments at end):

```
template<typename M, typename I, typename... Args>
arma::mat f(M matrix, I position, Args... args) 
{
    std::vector<arma::mat> matrixList;

    while(position > matrixList.size()) 
    {
        matrixList.push_back(eye<arma::mat>(2,2));
    }

    matrixList(position-1) = matrix;

    //Up until here, it's satisfied the first pair of arguments.
    //However, if I call f(args...) now, it'll just re-initialize matrixList
}
```

Is there a workaround that I'm missing?

Comment: It's exactly the same workaround as a "normal" recursive function :)

Comment: Are you suggesting that the stuff after declaring matrixList should be put in another function g(std::vector<arma::mat>& matrixList, args...), and do recursion within g? As far as I understand variadic templates, since g has only one argument preceding args..., wouldn't the arguments only be unpacked one at a time? I need them unpacked two at a time for the assignments to make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you are going to calculate the return value (I don't understand that sort of math yet), but if you calculate it from the final `matrixList`, you can do a wrapper around the function:

```
template<typename... Args>
arma::mat calculateSomething(Args&&... args) {
    std::vector<arma::mat> list;
    f(list, std::forward<Args...>(args...)); //First argument for recursion

    //Calculate return value
    return return_value;
 };
```

And `f` would look like this:

```
//Default case with just 1 argument
void f(std::vector<arma::mat>&) {}

template<typename M, typename I, typename... Ts>
void f(std::vector<arma::mat>& matrixList, M matrix, I position, Ts... args) 
{
    while(position > matrixList.size()) 
    {
        matrixList.push_back(eye<arma::mat>(2,2));
    }

    //This is not valid syntax, no idea what you are trying to do here
    //matrixList(position-1) = matrix;

    //recursive call
    f(matrixList, args...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that got it working, although I still don't fully understand how forwarding works... I need to read up on it. I'll post the finished code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Building off Rakete1111's suggestions, this is the code as I intended it to work. It generates k-qubit [Heisenberg interactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_model_(quantum)).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

const arma::cx_mat eye = "(1,0) (0,0); (0,0) (1,0)";
const arma::cx_mat sx = "(0,0) (1,0); (1,0) (0,0)";
const arma::cx_mat sy = "(0,0) (0,-1); (0,1) (0,0)";
const arma::cx_mat sz = "(1,0) (0,0); (0,0) (-1,0)";

void ArgsToMatrixList(std::vector<arma::cx_mat>&) {}

template<typename M, typename I, typename... Ts>
void ArgsToMatrixList(std::vector<arma::cx_mat>& matrixList, M matrix, I position, Ts... args)
{
    while(position > matrixList.size())
    {
        matrixList.push_back(eye);
    }

    matrixList[position - 1] = matrix;

    ArgsToMatrixList(matrixList, args...);
}

template<typename... Args>
arma::cx_mat J(Args&&... args)
{
    std::vector<arma::cx_mat> list;

    ArgsToMatrixList(list, std::forward<Args>(args)...); //First argument for recursion

    //Calculate return value

    arma::cx_mat return_value = list.front();
    for(int i = 1; i < list.size(); ++i)
    {
        return_value = arma::kron(return_value, list[i]);
    }

    return return_value;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    arma::cx_mat example = J(sx, 1, sy, 2, sz, 3);
    std::cout << example << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```